# On adding parent component on top of a component, state of child get transferred to parent

Tags: reactjs, state

and i am doing this

first time:

```
this.setstate({
windows: <Window title="Window 1>
         </Window>
```

});

second time:

```
this.setstate({
    windows: <Window title="Window 2">
                 {this.state.windows}
             </Window>
});
```

Now the problem is state values are stored inside window 1, this gets transferred to window 2 and window 1 state get reset.
I want to keep state of window 1 inside window 1 component, and create new state of window 2

Comment: Why do you use same `state` for 2 different states ? Better manage `parentWindows` and `childWindows` as states instead of `windows`

Comment: that makes complete sense to me now. I was newbie at that time trying to solve an interview when i posted this question... ;)
btw thanks